# removing part of a value from variable using sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following value from a variable .

`manager&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=314C54E5671790D592A37C2C4A6B9AAF`

I need to modify the above variable to remove &amp from it. SO , the variable should like this

`manager&;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=314C54E5671790D592A37C2C4A6B9AAF`

Please suggest

Comment: You removed `amp`, not `&amp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your variable in a file and was able to do what you wanted with sed.  The trick to make sure you do not remove any other references to just amp is to include the & as part of the substitution.

```
$ cat /tmp/file
manager&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=314C54E5671790D592A37C2C4A6B9AAF

$ cat /tmp/file | sed 's/\&amp/\&/g'
manager&;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=314C54E5671790D592A37C2C4A6B9AAF
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/&amp;/\&;/g' <<<"yourString"
```

The above line should help.

#### example:

```
kent$  sed 's/&amp;/\&;/g'<<< "foo&amp;bar&amp;blah"
foo&;bar&;blah
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can use Parameter Expansion - Pattern substitution to remove a substring:

```
VAR='manager&amp;org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=314C54E5671790D592A37C2C4A6B9AAF'
echo ${VAR/&amp}
```